# ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-5, asp.net-mvc-5.2

We have a SQL Server with multiple database (different schema) and i need to develop an application in **ASP.NET MVC & Entity Framework** to connect to any of these database in runtime and perform DML operations. If a new database is added to the SQL Server then the application should able to connect to this new database without any configuration/code change. I am exactly looking for DML operation handled by **myLittleAdmin**

Can anyone advice me on this please

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to do this with Entity Framework. Entity Framework operates in two different instances, Code-first & Database-first.

The former being writing your relevant model classes for your data first and then Entity Framework will work out a database schema based upon those classes handling foreign key references etc automatically based on the references between models.

The latter is effectively the opposite, you define the database schema and Entity Framework produces the model classes from this. I have always found this method to be cleaner as you have more control over the database structure and I find it more difficult to make mistakes.

In your situation Entity Framework needs to know before hand the structure of the database to enable it to read from it so it cannot "connect to this new database without any configuration/code change". If you can provide more information about what you are wanting then I may be able to help.

I recently created an asset management system which could store generic assets which would traditionally be stored in separate tables, this solution was developed using Entity Framework but the database was designed in such a way that it could handle generic asset objects and store them i.e. if we created a new asset type then no database change was required hence there was no code change for Entity Framework either.